# Can't get ngrok, and my python script to use the same port

Tags: python, flask, ngrok

I imported flask into my python script, and I'm using ngrok to make it accessible.

```
The ASK_APPLICATION_ID has not been set. Application ID verification disabled.
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
* Restarting with stat
The ASK_APPLICATION_ID has not been set. Application ID verification disabled.
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger pin code: 288-130-002
```

In ngrok the web interface if set to: http://127.0.0.1:4040

Whenever I try to set the python script to the same port (app.run(port="4040)), then run ngrok, ngrok changes its port to 4041.

If I run ngrok first, then set the port to ngrok's port, I get the error that the port is in use.

Answer (score 1):

start the flask application at 5000 port and then start ngrok

```
./ngrok http 5000
```

ngrok will provide the url which then forwards requests to your app running at 5000